# Make a list of dates of a ImageCollection (Landsat) and use it as a DateFilter on another Dataset (Daymet V3)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to make a comparison of the temperature evolution in a region, using Landsat and Daymetv3, but DaymetV3 have a daily information, and Landsat not. And i want to use the same dates on both.

Do you have some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way of doing this would be to get the Landsat imagery you want and map a function to extract the DayMet data for each date and location then combine it with the Landsat data. Here is an example:

```
var daymet = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/ORNL/DAYMET_V3");

var landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
  // change to where ever you like
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point([-122.431, 37.692])) 
  // change to whenever you like
  .filterDate('2019-01-01','2020-01-01');


// Apply the join.
var landsatDaymet = landsat.map(function(img){
  // get the landsat date
  var date = img.date();
  // filter the daymet data for the first image that coincides with the landsat date
  var met = ee.Image(
    daymet.filterDate(date.advance(-23,'hour'),date.advance(12,'hour'))
      .first()
  );
  // add the met bands to the landsat image
  return img.addBands(met.clip(img.geometry()));
});

print(landsatDaymet);
```

There is probably a more efficient way of doing this with joins but this at least gets the job done.